# Express res.render triggered by app.post

Tags: node.js, express

Within the stub created by [express application generator](http://expressjs.com/starter/generator.html), I've created a new view called `test`.

I am unable to invoke `test` using:

```
app.post('/test', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('test');
});
```

It seems surprising, because `app.get` below is getting rendered as expected:

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('test');
});
```

I have further tried the following, but it is still not rendering the page:

```
app.post('/test', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('within app.post'); // this is getting logged
    res.redirect('/test');
});
```

Please help. How can I render `test` from a post method ?

Comment: How do you make POST request?

Comment: @vanadium23 ... I'm using jquery `        $.ajax({
            url: "/test",
            type: "POST" })`

Comment: Try to send some json back to  res.send({ some: 'json' }); to locate that it is template problem.

Comment: @vanadium23 ... I tried sending json back, and i'm getting this error at the client 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o' ... but note that the template is working fine (because app.get renders the template)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So probably there is problem with javascript code. I am add code below to file index.js in routes folder, and template is rendering:

```
router.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {title: 'GET test'});
});

router.post('/test', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {title: 'POST test'});
});
```

Try to send request via curl:

```
curl -v -XPOST http://localhost:3000/test
```

Or use chrome or firefox extension to make request.

Comment: I think the problem was with how I called POST using $.ajax ... Removing `contentType: "application/json"` solved it for me. Thanks.

Comment: @KayaToast I got  the  same problem, can you describe  how you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are getting confused with `redirect` and `render`, as per my knowledge you need to have one router method which will render the required page and whenever you want land on that page you can use `redirect` call. For e.g.

```
// This will render the index.html page
app.get('/login', function(req,res) {
  res.render('index.html');
});

// This will redirect to above page
app.post('/homepage', function(req,res) {
  res.redirect('/login');
});
```

Comment: It's futher seacrh of problem. In top there is an example of res.render.

Comment: I mean use different route paths. As you per your example you have used same path to render and redirect.user get verb to render the page and post redirect to it.

Comment: @PriyanshuShekhar Tried it just now. Isn't rendering. Thanks

Comment: I get the following error using `redirect`: ```UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way of doing it, but you really want your render in one place for each route. I use .all() to handle the page rendering regardless of whether something has been posted.

```
app.post('/test', function(req, res, next) {
  // Do something with posted data
  next();
})
app.all('/test', function(req, res) {
  // res.render the page
});
```