# redirect to login page if haven't login in a post request

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
app.post("/customer/goods/available/disableGoods", auth.restrict,
        auth.acl([__FEATUREENUM.FP_SALE_GOODS]),
        postDisableGoodsHandler);}

exports.restrict = function (req, res, next) {
    logger.enter();
    if (req.session.operator) {
    if (req.url.indexOf("customer") > -1 && 
      req.session.operator.operatorType == "CUSTOMER") {
      return next();
    }
    if (req.url.indexOf("customer") > -1 && 
      req.session.operator.operatorType != "CUSTOMER") {
      logger.debug("您所访问的页面"+req.url+"没有权限");
      return res.redirect("/no_permission")
    }
    if (req.url.indexOf("customer") == -1 && 
    req.session.operator.operatorType == "CLIENT") {
      return next();
    }}
    logger.ndump("url", req.url);var nextTo = 
    encodeURIComponent(req.url);res.redirect("/loginNew?nextTo=" + 
    nextTo);};


    app.post("/loginNew", getLoginHandler);


    function getLoginHandler(req, res) {
    logger.enter();

    var nextTo = req.param('nextTo');
    logger.ndump("nextTo", nextTo);
    if (!nextTo)
      nextTo = APPURL;

    nextTo = encodeURIComponent(nextTo);

    dataService.commonData(req, function (data) {
      data = underscore.extend(data, {passHolder: "", nextTo: nextTo});
      data['paginator'] = {};
      res.render("pages/common/login.ejs", {data: data});
    });
  }
```

[image: This is the image]

As these, I want to use a middleware auth. resctrict to check if the status is login in a post request, otherwise, redirect to login page. I have got the response, but the browser didn't jump to a new page as I spect.

Comment: use req.redirect

Comment: I have tried, actually req.redirect is not a function

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't declare `var nextTo` twice. 
Maybe you should try to make session data like `req.session.loggedIn` and then check.
Like:

```
if(!req.session.loggedIn){
    encodeURIComponent(req.url);res.redirect("/loginNew?nextTo=" + 
    nextTo);};
}
```

Comment: thx so much ,now the point is the browser can't load to the login page ,even the redirect is already success

Comment: no error in fact ,,, response is a html doc as the picture I have post

Comment: Hmmm, okay so what do you want it to do? Try to clear your cookies

Comment: I spect the browser can load to login page  just  act as   
 window.location.href = '/loginNew';

Comment: You can redirect with res.redirect("/loginNew") as you did up there

Comment: look there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888907/express-res-render-triggered-by-app-post ,I think I might in the same situation

Comment: Hmm, then maybe try the solution there.. I dont have ideas anymore :D